# "eval is not a function" when using iframe and Greasemonkey/Scriptish

Tags: iframe, greasemonkey, scriptish

Is there any way I can get this piece of code to work inside Greasemonkey/Scriptish, or would I have to inject it into the webpage itself?

```
body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
fakeConsole = 'window.top._console';
injected = document.getElementById("sandbox") ? true : false;
sandboxframe = injected ? document.getElementsById("sandbox") : document.createElement('iframe');
sandbox = null;

if (!injected) {
   body.appendChild(sandboxframe);
   sandboxframe.setAttribute('id', 'sandbox');
   sandboxframe.setAttribute('style', "display:none")
}

var p = sandboxframe.contentWindow.eval('1 + 1');
console.log(p);
```

This code does work when using source:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

But not when using in a Greasemonkey script, I have observed there's some kind of security barrier I'm not quite familiar with and attempted to use unsafeWindow to bypass XPCNativeWrapper.

Please shed some light on this.

Comment: There is very seldom a need for `eval` -- if you post what you are doing there might be a better way to do it.  That said, try `unsafeWindow.eval`.  However, unsafeWindow is *exactly* what it sounds like...  Really, let us help you avoid `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. The code has an error; `getElementsById` is not a function.
2. That code otherwise ***does work*** in Greasemonkey 1.0 or later, if the `@grant none` directive applies.  More on this below.
3. For Scriptish, all other browsers, and Greasemonkey scenarios where `@grant none` is not possible; you will have to ***"inject"*** the code.  More on this below.
4. As Jeremy J Starcher says, `eval()` should be avoided as much as possible.  `eval()` makes performance, maintenance, debugging, and security much harder.

## For Greasemonkey 1.0, and later:

In *some* scenarios, Greasemonkey no longer uses the `XPCNativeWrapper`. See [the doc for the `@grant` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant).

So this means that (1) If your script uses no `GM_` functions and (2) the script specifies `@grant none`, then your code will run as-is (excepting the `getElementsById` typo).

Note that no other scripting engine does this. (For darn good reasons.  Greasemonkey's new behavior concerning `@grant`, and the sandbox, is controversial at best.)

If you wish to use `GM_` functions, then you must inject the iframe code.  See the next section.

## For Scriptish, Privileged Greasemonkey, Chrome, etc.:

Scriptish, Sandboxed Greasemonkey, Chrome, etc. all do not handle iframes well from within their respective sandboxes.  (See [these Q's, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey+iframe).)

The only reliable way to run this kind of code from a GM/userscript is to *inject* it.  Like so:

```js
function gmMain () {
    body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    fakeConsole = 'window.top._console';
    injected = document.getElementById("sandbox") ? true : false;
    sandboxframe = injected ? document.getElementById("sandbox") : document.createElement('iframe');
    sandbox = null;

    if (!injected) {
       body.appendChild(sandboxframe);
       sandboxframe.setAttribute('id', 'sandbox');
       sandboxframe.setAttribute('style', "display:none")
    }

    var p = sandboxframe.contentWindow.eval('1 + 1');
    console.log(p);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, gmMain);

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have successfully created a JavaScript "console" that users can access and (ab)use to their liking. My entire global scope is waiting to be exploited. Plus it has an amazing interpreter that produces human-readable info a la Firebug console. Isn't that absolutely thrilling?

Comment: You're welcome!  And, uh yes, I suppose that could be thrilling.